# Application icon upload pop-up not showing in Google Drive SDK in Google API Console

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-console

When trying to configure Google Drive SDK via Google API Console I am unable to upload an required Application Icon because the upload pop-up doesn't open properly.

When I click "Select" button to upload either one of the suggested icons I get a blank screen and unable to upload required icon (dl from: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8B7dx72Jp0keDdnMElVbVd6c2c)

If I look at the Javascript Console I can see the following error:
Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/picker?white=true&nav=(('photo-upload')('photos'...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Any advice?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a comment in Google Plus/Google Drive Developers (https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037) that this is a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Picker can't be shown in a frame.
I followed the url shown in console holding Shift.
It has opened ok in a new window. See screenshots.

terentyev dot com /picker.jpg
terentyev dot com /picker window.jpg

Though picker appears it does not upload icon files to api console. At least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to upload a application icon in drive sdk but it is not showing the upload icon in google crome browser but when I tried it in Internet explorer is https://docs.google.com/picker?white=true&nav=(('photo-upload')%2C('photos'))&thumbs=16-c%2Corig&relayUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fapis%2Fconsole%2Frpc_relay.html&protocol=gadgets&rpctoken=dz5c6om9eyfw&rpcService=af72ilx8mgfu

but here i am able to upload but not able to save and select